# Windows GUI tool to combine text files from sub folders into a single file?

Tags: windows

I am looking for a GUI (not command line) tool to combine text file from different sub folders into a single text file. I used to have such a tool and I can't find it on my computer. I specify the file extension and the top folder and the tool would combine all the files from all the sub folders. It also writes the full path of the filename before the contents of the file (a requirement).

Any similar tools? (don't mention a tool unless it meets all the requirements I mentioned)

Comment: We are not here to search the internet for you. There are several product search and recommendation sites, Google can find them for you as well.  Product and learning recommendations are off-topic on this site.

Comment: @Mokubai I am not asking anyone to search!! The question is for anyone who happened to come across a tool which meets my requirements. There's no way to search Google and find a tool which meets my requirements unless I download and test every single tool which shows up in Google and I don't have time for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [TXTCollector](http://bluefive.pair.com/txtcollector.htm).  Took about a five minute google search to find this . . .

Comment: It's buggy as in unusable and has a clunky UI. It said no files when I checked the 'Include Subfolders" checkbox even though it found 4 files in the top folder without checking the checkbox. "Stop scanning" is a confusing 'button'. No indication if it's actually scanning or scanning has ended. I will contact the author.

Comment: Ah, I didn't test it . . . just googled and found something that seemed like it worked.  Sorry that it's not very robust . . .

Comment: My workaround is to put all the files in one folder.